# Easy way to create repo with submodules from folder containing git repos as subfolders

Tags: git, submodule

My case is `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles` there I have some bundles/folders which are all git repos. If I create git repo at Bundles folder, which will be the easiest/fastest way to add all bundles as submodules to this repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working this way:

```
git init
for f in */**/.git; do
  git submodule add "$(git --git-dir="$f" config remote.origin.url)" "$(dirname "$f")"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git init
for f in *; do
    [[ -d $f ]] && git submodule add "./$f" "$f"
done
```

Comment: Got `remote (origin) does not have a url defined in .git/config` for every repository. As I understand relative form for repository assumes that all repos are in one location, but this is not my case.